# How to place the slider button to the far left and right hand side of the page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I recently placed a slider presentation in my site problem is that I want it to cover it from the far left to far right like a banner and also the image to resizes and fit the banner. Here is a picture of the slider so far:

Also wondering if the image and slider can also resize automatically with the size of the webpage. So that it is mobile friendly and the website wouldn't mess up when it is not in fullscreen.
[image]

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Croydon Cycles</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="shop-style.css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="images/favicon.png">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Karla" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="parallax.min.js"></script>
</head>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <header>
            <nav>
                <div class="menu-icon">
                    <i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="logo">
                    Croydon Cycles
                </div>
                <div class="menu">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Shop</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </header>
        <div class="slideshow-container">
            <div class="myslides fade">
                <div class="numbers">1 / 4</div>
                <div class="slider-1">
                    <img class="Fit" src="images/slider-1.jpg">
                </div>
                <div class="caption">Text 1</div>
            </div>
            <div class="myslides fade">
                <div class="numbers">2 / 4</div>
                <div class="slider-2">
                    <img src="images/2.jpg">
                </div>
                <div class="caption">Text 2</div>
            </div>
        <div class="myslides fade">
            <div class="numbers">3 / 4</div>
            <div><img src="images/3.jpg"></div>
            <div class="caption">Text 3</div>
        </div>
        <div class="myslides fade">
            <div class="numbers">4 / 4</div>
            <div><img src="images/4.jpg"></div>
            <div class="caption">Text 4</div>
        </div>
        <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
        <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div style="text-align:center">
        <span class="dots" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span> 
        <span class="dots" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span> 
        <span class="dots" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span> 
        <span class="dots" onclick="currentSlide(4)"></span> 
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var slideIndex = 1;
        showSlide(slideIndex);

        function plusSlides(n){
            showSlide(slideIndex += n);
        }

        function currentSlide(n) {
            showSlide(slideIndex = n);
        }

        function showSlide(n){
            var i;
            var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("myslides");
            var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dots");

            if (n > slides.length) { slideIndex = 1};

            if (n < 1) { slideIndex = slides.length};

            for (i=0;i<slides.length;i++) {
                slides[i].style.display = "none";
            };

            for (i=0;i<dots.length;i++) {
                dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active","");
            };

            slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
            dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
        }
    </script>
    <div class="content">
        <p> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Menu-toggle button
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".menu-icon").on("click", function() {
            $("nav ul").toggleClass("showing");
        });
    });

    // Scrolling Effect
    $(window).on("scroll", function() {
        if($(window).scrollTop()) {
            $('nav').addClass('black');
        }
        else {
            $('nav').removeClass('black');
        }
    })
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: verdana,sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
}

body {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue",sans-serif;
    font-weight: lighter;
}

header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    background: url(hero.jpg) no-repeat 50% 50%;
    background-size: cover;
}

.content {
    width: 94%;
    margin: 4em auto;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 30px;
    text-align: justify;
}


.logo {
    line-height: 60px;
    position: fixed;
    float: left;
    margin: 16px 46px;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
}

nav {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 60px;
    z-index:2;
}

nav ul {
    line-height: 60px;
    list-style: none;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    overflow: hidden;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: right;
    margin: 0;
    padding-right: 40px;
    transition: 1s;
}

nav.black ul {
    background: #000;
}

nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 16px 40px;;
}

nav ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.menu-icon {
    line-height: 60px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #000;
    text-align: right;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 15px 24px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #fff;
    display: none;
}

@media(max-width: 786px) {

    .logo {
          position: fixed;
          top: 0;
          margin-top: 16px;
    }

    nav ul {
          max-height: 0px;
          background: #000;
    }

    nav.black ul {
          background: #000;
    }

    .showing {
          max-height: 34em;
    }

    nav ul li {
          box-sizing: border-box;
          width: 100%;
          padding: 24px;
          text-align: center;
    }

    .menu-icon {
          display: block;
    }

}

body{
    font-family: verdana,sans-serif;

    margin: 0;

}

.slideshow-container{
    width: 800px;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
}

.numbers{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    padding: 8px 12px;
    font-size: 12px;
}

.myslides{
    display: none;
}

.prev , .next{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 16px;
    margin-top: -22px;
    border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.next{
    right: 0;
    border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

.prev:hover,.next:hover{
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

.caption{
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 8px;
    width: 100%;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding: 8px 22px;
}

.dots{
    width: 13px;
    height: 13px;
    background: gray;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 50%;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.fade{
    animation-name:fade;
    animation-duration:1.5s;
}

@keyframes fade{
    from {opacity: 0.4;}
    to {opacity: 1;}
}

.active, .dot:hover {
    background-color: #333;
}

.slider-1 {
    display: grid;
    height: 100%;
    z-index:0;
}

.Fit {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100vh;
    margin: auto;
    z-index:0;  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your slider is only 800px large and the prev and next determine their position from it so you need a larger container for them to get their position relative to it.

You can add a container with a width to 100% and move your buttons to it.

```css
.slideshow {

    width: 100%;

    position: relative;

    margin: auto;

}
```

```html
<div class="slideshow">
  <div class="slideshow-container">
  ....
  </div>
  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, really appreciate it.